# counterexample for limit of composite functions

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Does this claim true?

If $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(g(x))=\infty$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$.

I'm pretty sure that this is not true, but I can't think on example.
I have no assumptions on $f$ and $g$ except the limits.

Comment: Force $f$ to have two (or more) subsequences.  One, on the image of $g$ goes to $\infty$ and the other(s), do not.  For instance, for $x$ in the integers, $g(x) = 2x$ (so the image of $g$ is the even integers), and $f(x) = \begin{cases} x ,& x \text{ even} \\ 0 ,& x \text{ odd}\end{cases}$.

Comment: @EricTowers but $x$ is real, it is not have to be an integer.

Comment: Correct.  I have not solved your problem for you -- I have told you how to solve it yourself.